# Material Design checkbox creates a new row when inside datatables

Tags: html, css, datatables, materialize

does anyone uses this [link](https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/forms/basic-form-elements.html)

i am trying to use this checkbox

[image]

and the tag of them is like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_1" class="chk-col-red" checked />
<label for="md_checkbox_1">RED</label>
```

However i am trying to encorporate that in datatables and its working. here is the sample

[image]

the problem is the label next to the checkbox is empty i wonder why it creates so large space below.

[image]

I am very frustrated trying all the possibilities just to remove that does anyone encounter this?

Here is my code where I add the checkbox

```
var link = '../../php/submit_mail.php?key_id=' + arr_id.join();
        DTable = $('#tbl_user').DataTable({
                    "destroy": true,
                    "order": [],
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10,25, 50, 75, -1], [10,25, 50, 75, "All"]],
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "sAjaxSource": link,
                    'columnDefs': [{
                        'targets': 0,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta){
                            return '<input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_' + data + '" class="filled-in chk-col-blue chkall">' +
                                   '<label for="md_checkbox_' + data + '"></label>';
                        }
                    },
                    { targets: 0, orderable: false },
                    { className: "custom_right", "targets": [1] },
                    ],
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { mData: 'id' },
                        { mData: 'col1' }
                    ]
                });
```

Comment: how do you use it? The shown code is just a generic example... What is your code? What elements surround the Checkbox? What's your css for the element itself, and its surrounding elements?

Comment: Kindly make a fiddle and send us the link

Comment: edited my post to see where i put the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change 
[type="checkbox"] + label {
    height: 22px;
}
label {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

Comment: sir please feel free to use my code. I dont where to start based in your answer

Comment: If you look in your dev tools you'll see what css is set on your elemenr. You need to overwrite those.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the dev tools, which shows the css on the respective element?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your CSS:

```
[type="checkbox"] + label {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: try to add the same rule to the text in the same cell (in your example 11111)

Comment: still the same sir